# unknown JAXB implementation incase of SOAP FAULT

Tags: web-services, soap, jaxb

I am running soap webservice and in case of error I am getting below exception:

```
[Loaded com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.AttachmentMarshallerImpl from file:/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/com.sun.xml.ws.jaxws-rt_2.2.jar]
Feb 18, 2017 2:06:47 AM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit handle
SEVERE: Unknown JAXBContext implementation: class com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl
com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: Unknown JAXBContext implementation: class com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.getJAXBFactory(BindingContextFactory.java:207)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.create(BindingContextFactory.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.create(JAXBMessage.java:167)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAP11Fault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:439)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAPFaultMessage(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:216)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAPFaultMessage(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:204)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:425)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:868)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:225)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:197)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteRequestAdapter.execute(ExecuteRequestAdapter.java:21)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:147)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:119)
```

Comment: solved it by decreasing some web lib versions (netty, jetty e.t.c.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried looking for answer on various blogs but could not find the answer. then i de-compiled jars and found out below which helped in resolving this error . Error was because of classes with different version in JDK and weblogic.

```
-Djavax.xml.bind.JAXBContext=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the decompiling! It works!
But in the console I have this error : SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /IBM/console/ has not been defined. Did you fix it?

Comment: in Java 9 and onwards, the property is 
`-Djavax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory`